# How to automate On screen keyboard(Virtual Keyboard) using java and selenium without using Robot class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-applications, ui-automation, automation-testing

I have to enter input using virtual keyboard i.e. on screen keyboard using java and selenium i want to automate the on screen keyboard.
I want top perform key actions on the On screen keyboard.

I have tried java selenium.
I am able to lauch the on screen keyboard but not able to perform action on it.

Comment: If it's not in the DOM, Selenium can't interact with it.  If it is, include the HTML markup and code you've tried.